# Convert Revit Model into JSON for three.js

Tags: php, json, three.js, revit

Has anybody/does anybody know of a way of a way to use php, in particular `json_encode()` to convert a Autodesk Revit file into JSON for three.js:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3

.. Or the new Model format 4.  I know this site:

http://www.greentoken.de/onlineconv/

Does a lot of conversion, but not Revit.  There is vA3C (https://va3c.github.io/) which has plugins to do it, but I really want an in-browser script using PHP.

Comment: Autodesk Revit supports several file formats dedicated for interoperability (.dwf, .fbx, .etc), while Revit .rvt files themselves can only be opened by a handful of Autodesk products. You are not likely to find a readymade .php solution for processing .rvt files, and you really shouldn't need to.

Comment: @Paul-Jan True.  I could use a different file format, but besides IFC.. what would you go with?  I haven't found a ready made converter for rvt, dwg, dwf, or nwd...  I did find a DXF creator class: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7954-PHP-Generate-CAD-files-in-the-AutoCAD-DXF-format.html#download